# Mutiple date selection list column?

Tags: custom-field-types

Does anyone know of a CodePlex web part or a way the implement a multiple date selections field on a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know of any pre-made Custom Field Types (free or otherwise) that implement this kind of functionality. I'm not going to say such a thing doesn't exist, but I can't imagine there's much call for someone putting the effort to develop a solution that covers such a narrow requirement.

I can tell you that such a thing is certainly *conceivable* by coding a Custom Field Type, but unless your requirements are very specific and/or rigid I would advise towards simply using two or more DateTime fields.